# How to find out the device screen resolution and density to set same UI display on the emulator and device?

Tags: android

I need to set same UI in both device and emulator (In my application the UI changing in emulator and device)for that i need to know the screen resolution and density of the device . I don't know how to find out that .Let me know how to find out that in device.

Thanks,

Lakshmanan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```